# BigCommerce Stencil - Category Products Per Page

Tags: bigcommerce

We are seeing an issue beginning yesterday where the Front Matter attribute for products per page defined in our custom layout file is not working.

```
---
category:
    products:
        limit: 48
---

{{inject "categoryProductsPerPage" 48}}
```

I have hardcoded the products per page, but somehow only 21 products are being displayed per page. The value 21 is not located anywhere in the config file, or front matter, or backend theme settings. Regardless of where I change this value, it is not reflected in the number of products resources returned. I am only experiencing this issue on one particular store, so I'm not quite sure what to think.

Has anyone else seen this problem in the last few days?

Comment: Can you email me the store url that you are seeing this on at alyss@bigcommerce.com?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding or editing the `categorypage_products_per_page` setting in your theme's `config.json` (at the root of the project)? I was able to change the number of products displayed on a category page without adding any Front Matter to the top of my category page template.

My theme (based off Cornerstone 1.6.4) was explicitly set to `12`. Here's how my `config.json` now reads (major pieces redacted):

```
{
   ...
   "settings": {
      ...
      "categorypage_products_per_page": 24,
      ...
   }
   ...
}
```

and that works perfectly.